# Problem with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to change my URL for

```
http://www.tomttb.com/school/index.php?page=p/logbook/my.php
```

To

```
http://www.tomttb.com/school/logbook/my
```

I now have this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=p/$1/$2.php [L]
```

It works, he gives me index.php, but the images, stylesheets, etc. won't load because the browser thinks he's in the folder http://www.tomttb.com/school/logbook/my.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is to add a `<base>` tag to each page, which, in your case, could probably be accomplished by adding it to index.php.

From W3C, the base tag's href attribute

> specifies an absolute URI that acts as the base URI for resolving relative URIs

So, you could add something like

```
<base href="http://www.tomttb.com/school/">
```

to cause all relative paths to resolve using the specified URL (http://www.tomttb.com/school/), instead of the URL that the browser sees (http://www.tomttb.com/school/logbook/my)